# VBA : 'Defined or Object Defined Error' at If And Then Function

Tags: vba, excel

I getting error for my VBA Macro at this line :

```
If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 15) = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19) And Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24).Value <> "0" Then
```

This is my code :

```
    x = 1
    y = 16
    Do
        If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 15) = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19) And Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24).Value <> "0" Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 21).Copy
            Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 21).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 22) = "Anode Foil not scan completely"
            With Sheets("Check Foil").Range(Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 21), Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24)).Borders
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Weight = xlThin
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
            y = y + 1
        Else
            Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 22) = "Foil Info Not Found"
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop Until Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 15) = ""

    Sheets("Check Foil").Range("M16:X1016").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Sheets("Check Foil").Range("M:M").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Sheets("Check Foil").Range("N16:O1016").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Sheets("Check Foil").Range("P16:V1016").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    y = 16
    Do
        If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24) <= Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 23) - (Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 23) * 0.1)) And Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24).Value <> "0" Then
            Sheets("Check Foil").Range(Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 13), Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Loop Until Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 14) = ""

    Worksheets("Check Foil").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

    MsgBox "Program Complete Run"

End Sub
```

Comment: This line may be getting same error : If Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24) <= Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 23) - (Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 23) * 0.1)) And Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24).Value <> "0" Then

Comment: What are the values of `x`, `y`, `Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 15)`, `Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19)` and `Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24)` when the code crashes?

Answer (score 0):

You actual Problem , You are missing ".value" in first comparison.
so :

```
 If (Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 15).Value = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 19).Value) And (Sheets("Check Foil").Cells(y, 24).Value <> "0") Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 21).Copy
```

But this could be improved:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws_foil As Worksheet
Dim ws_data As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws_foil = wb.Sheets("Check Foil")
Set ws_foil = wb.Sheets("Data")

foil_data = ws_foil.Cells(y, 15).Value
data_data = ws_data.Cells(x, 19).Value

foil_data1 = ws_foil.Cells(y, 24).Value

If ((foil_data = data_data) And (foil_data1 <> 0)) Then
    ws_data.Cells(x, 21).Copy
End If
```

Comment: `.Value` is (indirectly) the default property of a `Range` object.  While personally I prefer to always use it, it **will** work without it.